# WPF Control, Property that binds to a List on View Model, would like to define the list in Xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have been working on a WPF UI Control.

I have defined a dependency property which is a List of strings.

This binds with a list property on a view model as expected.

What I would like to do is have the option to define the list in the XAML rather than bind to a list on the view model.

```
<local:MyControl MyList = "one,two,three">
```

The MyList Property on my control.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyListProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("MyList", typeof(List<string>), typeof(MyControl));
```

Comment: What is the type of your `MyList` property? `System.Collections.IList`? Something else?

Comment: You may write a [TypeConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typeconverter?view=netframework-4.8) that can parse `"one,two,three"`.

Comment: @Clemens, I like the TypeConverter idea as this looks a lot tidier!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to support initialization of a list from a string that contains comma-separated elements, like

```
MyList="one, two, three"
```

you would register a custom [`TypeConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typeconverter?view=netframework-4.8).

Note that the code below uses `IList<string>` as property type, which provides greater flexibility in the types assignable to the property, and thus simpler implementation of the TypeConverter (which returns a `string[]`).

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyListProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(MyList),
            typeof(IList<string>),
            typeof(MyControl));

    [TypeConverter(typeof(StringListConverter))]
    public IList<string> MyList
    {
        get { return (IList<string>)GetValue(MyListProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyListProperty, value); }
    }
}

public class StringListConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(
        ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        return sourceType == typeof(string);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(
        ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        return ((string)value).Split(
            new char[] { ',', ' ' },
            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was trying to get the System.Configuration.CommaDelimitedStringCollectionConverter to work to no avail, @Clemens answer worked perfectly - thank you.

Comment: Which won't work because `CommaDelimitedStringCollection` does not implement `IList<string>`.